# How to upload excel file and verify about that columns are valid

Tags: excel, angular

I want to upload an excel file and verifying those columns and get an alert for that column are valid or not Please kind enough to let me know how to implement that by angular 7.:D

Answer (score 1):

You have use `FileReader` to read the file. Here is a small example

```
bulkUploadField: any;
convertFile(csvfile: any) {   
this.bulkUploadField = csvfile.target.files[0];
let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();   reader.readAsText(this.bulkUploadField);  
let lastIndex = 0; 
this.csvData = [];
reader.onload = (e) => {  
  console.log('csv file uploaded and coming to onload')
  let csv: any = reader.result;
  let allTextLines = csv.split(/\n/);  
  this.csvHeader = allTextLines[0].split(',');
  if(!(this.csvHeader[0].toLowerCase().trim()  == 'title' &&
  this.csvHeader[1].toLowerCase().trim()  == 'contact_name'))
  {
    this.toast.show('Uploaded data is not in proper format','error');
    return;
  }
  let errorMsg = ""
  for (let i = 1; i < allTextLines.length - 1; i++) {
    let data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
    let unname = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$")
    if(!unname.test(data[1]))
    {
      errorMsg = "Uploaded File contains wrong format for contact name at row no -" + i.toString() + " :" + data[1];
      this.toast.show(errorMsg,'error');
      this.isFileUploaded = false
      return
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Use the convert File function in the click function of the input field

```
<input #bulkUploadFile type="file" (change)="convertFile($event)" accept=".csv" mdbFileSelect  >
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank a lot, I think this will very helpful and I will go through and I will let you know